Whatapp bussines api message type text not received
For type "template" the message is sent and received but for type "text" not working, I receive the message as success but the message does not reach the recipient. what can be the problem?
Message sent successfully:
Array
(
    [messaging_product] => whatsapp
    [contacts] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [input] => +40
                    [wa_id] => 407
                )

        )

    [messages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => wamid.adsasdHBgLNDA3NTM0NzQ4MDYVAgARGBI2Mjc0REJBNkRCMzIxQjc0OEUA
                    [message_status] => accepted
                )

        )

)

/*this is not working $data = [
    'messaging_product' => 'whatsapp',
    "recipient_type"=> "individual",
    "to"=> $to,
    "type"=>"text",
    "text"=>[
        "preview_url"=>true,
        "body"=>"Your verification code is 1234"
    ]
];*/

//this is working
 $data = [
    'messaging_product' => 'whatsapp',
    'to' => $to,
    'type' => 'template',
    'template' => [
        'name' => 'hello_world',
        'language' => [
            'code' =>'en_US'
        ]
    ]
];

